# YouCompleteMe is not autocompleting functions

Tags: c++, vim, youcompleteme

YMC has not been working the way I have been expecting it. The only instance it works in is when there is a scope operator (std::) and the dot operators on objects. However, it does not work with functions. I am working with the SDL library and none of the functions or structs autocomplete. I always have to type it out. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Are you referring to the auto-completion popup that sometimes appears in IDEs?

Comment: I'm using the Vim text editor for programming. The plugin I'm having issues with is YouCompleteMe(YMC). It functions the same way that Visual Studio does it. However, for some reason, the autocomplete does not work when I'm typing a basic function from a library.

Answer (score 1):

You can always force the YCM autocompletion by pressing `C-n` (Ctrl+N) after you start typing the function name. With a very high chance pressing `Tab` will also work.

Answer (score 1):

Using Ctrl+SpaceBar will force autocompletion suggestions without any triggers that would otherwise do it automatically.